# using java and fft for sound file manipulation

Tags: java, database, fft

I am a musician/singer/songwriter,

I was hoping someone might know of information already out that does some if not all of what I'm trying to achieve.
I record song ideas into raw digital wav files using only my voice to emulate instruments ( vocal melody, bass, guitar, drums, etc.) into a song structure (verse, chorus, bridge).
I was hoping that java/fft could be used to slice each mili-second into an array that could be broken down into notes and riffs that I am singing.

Here is a list of some of the steps I see that need to be done with my wav files.

1. Find out the note that I'm singing. The software would take each note and nudge it into the nearest "true note" (a4=440hz).
2. It would take the notes and find out which key or possible keys the song may be in.
3. From a very large database of real songs, the software would make chord suggestions and placement suggestions depending on the genre the song is in.
4. It would take the riffs ( any sequence of more than 3 notes done more than 3 times in a song) and create loops with a drop down box of alternative voiceings and randomizing.
   There is much more, but this should show you the basics of what I’m trying to do.

If there aren’t programs already written that already do all or part of this, would it be possible for me to write a program that uses java and fft to slice every millisecond into an array to determine notes?

I have read some  java/fft material and it is way over my head mostly (I have studied a little java) but I was hoping someone might be able to lead me in the right direction.

Comment: This question is not suited for SO, you're better off seeking advice from fellow musicians. Note that each of the steps you describe contains hard problems that cannot be solved exactly. Judging from the fact you don't seem to realize how complex/large a problem e.g. step 3 presents, any attempts to "just DIY" are most certainly futile.

Comment: I won't say you can't do this, because you might be exceptionally bright and talented and you might come up with some revolutionary way of achieving it. But, it is extremely unlikely that you'll be able to do this, especially given your level of java skills. As Durandal said above, this is an incredibly difficult problem to solve, and requires higher order mathematics, not to mention superlative java skills.

Comment: Can you post a compressed audio file of you singing (Dropbox, etc.)? I’m looking at these [spectrograms](http://iie.fing.edu.uy/~rocamora/mscthesis/examples.html) of, e.g., the Beatles, and curious if your audio is that clean. (And don’t listen to the naysayers—what you’re asking is the kernel of a [great startup idea](http://paulgraham.com/notnot.html). The individual pieces are great signal processing projects that I think ought to be individually doable (though I’d use Python/Julia, for faster prototyping). Combining individually-working pieces into a single app… is a bit more challenging.)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and suggestions. Yes even you naysayers, for you naysayers have always been a part  of the process of creation.